# Include WordPress files in an independent script

Tags: php, wordpress

Which file of WordPress would I include in a totally independent PHP script which not need to generate a webpage as output, only modify the database with the WordPress classes and functions?

Comment: Oh yeah, this is the same question and solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it should be in its own new file. I could elaborate if you gave more information about exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to write a script which scrape CSV files from shops and insert the products from the CSV into the database.

Comment: When and how is the script going to be called? CRON?

Comment: Yeah, it's run in every hour.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found it.

If you simply include the wp-load.php from the root directory of the WordPress site, you got the full functionallity of WordPress, but it will not generate output.